# Equilibria of 2x2 linear system

Tags: convergence-divergence, dynamical-systems

Consider the $2\times2$ linear system given by $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 3\\-1 & 0\end{pmatrix}.$$ We wish to look at the behavior of the plane under iterations of $A$. The eigenvalues of this matrix are purely imaginary. In general, solutions of such a map are given by $X_n = c_1 \lambda_1^n v_1 + c_2 \lambda_2^n v_2$. How do we reach the solution of such a system?

Comment: This system has as general solution
$$
x_1(t) = \sqrt{3} c_2 \sin \left(\sqrt{3} t\right)+c_1 \cos \left(\sqrt{3} t\right)\\
x_2(t)=c_2 \cos \left(\sqrt{3} t\right)-\frac{c_1 \sin \left(\sqrt{3}
   t\right)}{\sqrt{3}}
$$

Comment: A few more details would help. Is thin an ODE or a difference equation? If it's a difference equation, you need $|\lambda_n|=1$ for each eigenvalue $\lambda_n$ to get a center.

Comment: It is a difference equation, so this would explain the behavior of the orbits. @Cesar, how did you arrive at that?

Comment: @DerekAdams: Please [edit] additional information into your question.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I've cut out some of the superfluous/incorrect information, and added a short question at the end that would suffice.

Comment: @DerekAdams: You can take the derivative of the first equation and get $$x'' = 3y' = -3x$$ Now, just solve $$x'' = -3x$$ Then substitute $x$ into the second equation and solve for $y$. There are also many methods to solve these sorts of systems like eigenvalues/eigenvectors, matrix exponential, fundamental matrix...

Comment: @Moo it's a difference equation, not differential.

Comment: Sorry, I was just replying to how they got the result from the first posted comment was asked about by the OP. I should have made that clearer.

Comment: Ah, I see. Then no problem there!

Answer (score 0):

Your system is
$$
\begin{pmatrix} x_{n+1} \\ y_{n+1} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 3 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x_n \\ y_n \end{pmatrix},
$$
or
$$
x_{n+1} = 3y_n \qquad \text{ and } \qquad y_{n+1} = -x_n .
$$
These two difference equations can be combined
$$
x_{n+2} = 3y_{n+1} = -3 x_n.
$$
To solve $x_{n+2} + 3x_n = 0$ we make the guess $x \sim r^n$ where $r$ is some number we will find. Plugging this in gives the characteristic equation:
$$ r^{n+2} + 3 r^n = 0$$ implying that $r^2 = -3$ or $r = \pm \sqrt{-3}$. Plugging this back in for our guess for $x$ gives
$$ x_n = c_1 ( \sqrt{-3} )^n + c_2 ( - \sqrt{-3} )^n,$$
which can be written in a variety of ways, each helpful in different cases. Then we can easily find $y_n$ from this too since
$$
y_n = - x_{n-1} = -c_1 (\sqrt{-3})^{n-1} - c_2 ( - \sqrt{-3})^{n-1}.
$$
$c_1$ and $c_2$ are constants which depend on the initial state. The long-time behaviour is found by letting $n \to \infty$. You can see here that since $\sqrt{3}>1$ you will have solutions unbounded, as you mentioned (in your original post) you found numerically.